# Model on cakephp return me Array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Im working in the model on cakephp with this method

```
public function updateUserStatus($uus){
  if(isset($calor["valor1"])){

    $query1= $this->query("SELECT time from users where time = "'.$valor["valor1"].'";");        

    return "test".$query1;

  }

}
```

But when I `return "test".$query1 ;`  the view show me testArray
My question is How can i Get the value time from the query? 
thank for your help

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `$query1['time']`

Comment: i think you also need to correct your query to "SELECT time from users where time = '".$valor["valor1"]."'"

Comment: eheheh yeah, that happened because i write it very fast here, but thanks @Naeem

Comment: I suggest also to use `$this->find()` function for this, or at least put some safeguards against sql injection.

Comment: Why are you not using the CakePHP ORM? Your query is exploitable as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're concatenating a string with an array, and PHP will change the array to a string, which will be `Array`. `$query1` is an array containing your data, so just do:

```
return $query1;
```

And access your fields with the variable that will store the returned value.

If you want `'test'` to be associated with `$query1`, then it's better to:

```
return array('test' => $query1);
```